# Expect array inside object toEqual but unsorted

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have an object:

```
{
Alice: ['Bob','Charlie']
}
```

I want to make an unsorted expectation on the array, I tested:

```
expect(object).toEqual(
      expect.objectContaining({
        Alice: expect.arrayContaining(['Bob', 'Charlie'])
      })
    );
```

It's working but the array can obviously contain more data that I don't want.

If I do:

```
expect(object).toEqual(
      {
        Alice: ['Bob', 'Charlie']
      }
    );
```

it's working but only if `Bob` and `Charlie` are in this order.

I could possibly extract the array and sort it to compare it to a sorted expected array, but is there a cleaner way to do it?

Comment: [_"For additional Jest matchers maintained by the Jest Community check out jest-extended."_](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect) -> https://jest-extended.jestcommunity.dev/docs/matchers/Array#toincludesamemembersmembers

Comment: thanks for pointing jest-extended that I didn't knew but toIncludeAnyMembers is not applicable directly to my exemple, I need to extract the array first